# How to print the value of a variable in the color red using C

Tags: c, printf

I want to print colored text using C. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ANSI_COLOR_RED     "\x1b[31m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_GREEN   "\x1b[32m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_YELLOW  "\x1b[33m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_BLUE    "\x1b[34m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_MAGENTA "\x1b[35m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_CYAN    "\x1b[36m"
#define ANSI_COLOR_RESET   "\x1b[0m"

int main()
{
  char *string = "Test";

  printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RED     string     ANSI_COLOR_RESET);

  return 0;
}
```

When this is compiled, an error is outputted:

```
game.c:18:35: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘string’
printf("%s", ANSI_COLOR_RED     string     ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You can concatenate string literals (as in option 3 in the answer), but you can concatenate a literal with a variable, as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
printf ("\033[31;1m Red dragon \033[0m\n");
```

This is the way to do.

Also a better way would be to do it `ANSI`-way, using the macro.

```
printf ("%s%s%s\n", ANSI_COLOR_RED, string, ANSI_COLOR_RESET);
```

Another way to go about it would be

```
printf (ANSI_COLOR_RED "%s\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, string);
```

Comment: Or, better, `printf ("%s%s%s\n", ANSI_COLOR_RED, string, ANSI_COLOR_RESET);`

Comment: @AlexP.: Yes...even better.

Comment: Or even `printf (ANSI_COLOR_RED "%s\n" ANSI_COLOR_RESET, string);` `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.: I cant trust my net now it seems...switching the port takes the edit time...was doing this on my terminal. Thanks.. :)

Comment: Happens to me all the time.